# Container stuck with no status and no events

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I am using azure container instance for my services, but after some days of working the containers getting stuck and azure can not find them (return 404).
After the problem happen the service still has a public IP but nothing else.
All metrics show none usage and in the event tab there is an error that say "no events in the last hours".
I can not even connect to the container because it is say that the container does not exist.
The containers status contain nothing (not stopped, just dots like there is not value) and I can not start the containers but can stop them (witch is wired because azure complain that the does not exist).
After I stop the containers all the data (status and events) show the values of the last manual stop.

I have tried to run the docker in a regular server with out any problems. I also deny resources problem by monitor the resource usage.

Comment: Two options: delete the ACI and redeploy to a new ACI and see if you can reproduce (this might mean it's the container image you are using). If you don't want to do this (or you've done it and it is still a problem) then you should open a support ticket.

Comment: I have tried to delete all the resources (includes the resource group) and recreate them but it did not work.